# @font-face works locally but not on live website

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a website in production which uses @font-face to render fonts, and this works fine in a local environment but fails when uploaded to the live website.

The CSS file which links to the font files is in the root directory, and uses the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ColaborateLightRegular';
    src: url('css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.svg#webfontR2xcGGVv') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

The font is in the /css/fonts/ directory. I have tried  adding the following to an .htaccess file to try fix the issue but still to no avail:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm out of ideas really! I just find it very strange how I have no problems across browsers when viewing with XAMPP, but when I try and view it on my server (which is Apache) it wont work on any browser.

Comment: Have you tried getting a font file directly: http://server/css/fonts/ColabLig-webfont.eot ? What is returned?

Comment: It seems to redirect to the production sites home page.

Comment: Unfortunately it is on a password protected development area which I can't give access too. Sorry!

Comment: Have you checked the server logs, there might be some information in there to help.

Comment: Nothing in the log files of notice. I'm going to test the site on another development server and see if the server is the issue. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: OK, it appears to be an issue with the server I was testing on. I will have a look and figure out exactly what the problem is when I find it as I'm sure I'm not the only one in this situation! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good stuff. Hope it doesn't prove to be too taxing :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your CHMOD settings on the folders and make sure the server's not sending you a 403 back

Comment: With permissions set at 777, I can't seem to view the font files from the browser, it seems to redirect to the production sites home page.